# Getting started with ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, stata

I am 100% new to ArcGIS and I am feeling more than lost. I have found quite some tutorials on the web but they do not really help me - they explain nicely how to analyse perfectly prepared data and maps. But the dirty work to me seems completely uncovered. What I would like to do is the following

- For my country I have a Stata dataset on individuals and postcodes
- My second Stata dataset contains measurements and their coordinates
- For each individual I would like to know inverse weighted average distances to the x closest measurements

I guess ArcGIS is well suited for this. I managed to load a proper basemap and a layer containing postcodes. Now I face the following questions and I do not really know where to begin. How do I have to format my Stata-files? In which format (dbase, personal geodatabase...) do those data have to be? I´m very willing to work my way through, but I just have no idea where to start. Do you have some reference to a tutorial or so where such topics are covered - and not just how to change a color? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The questions you need answered to progress your ArcGIS for Desktop learnings are on-topic for this site but I recommend that you take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and review [What makes a good question?](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question) because our Q&A format works differently to a discussion forum.  That should give you some ideas on what **single** question you wish to ask here first, and then to edit your question to focus on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is joining data to your basemaps using Postcodes:**

Take your Stata dataset and make sure it is a format that ArcMap can read.  Typically, I use either a CSV file or an Excel spreadsheet.  If your basemap has postcodes, you can join your Stata dataset to the basemap and add those attributes to each feature of the basemap.  Then you can go ahead and try doing the spatial analysis (make sure you have the right license) on your data.

Follow the directions [Here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000002q000000) to learn about joining tables in ArcMap.  It is pretty simple.  Also, you would need to make sure your table is 'clean' to go into ArcMap.  It can get a bit picky at times.  If you have a specific problem that comes up when you're trying to join, post an update and a sample of your data.

**Dealing with your individual information:**

For the table that has individual information, do you have coordinates for each person?  I am assuming you're referring to individuals by houses or something?  If you are trying to create points for each individual then do some spatial analysis on each individual point instead of just joining to the Postcodes, you need to create a layer for that.  **If this is the case** do you have coordinates/addresses/etc for these points?  The next step would depend on what type of coordinates you have for individuals.

Provide a little more information about your data, and we can make things happen.